# 3rd party dns + Route53 failover

Tags: dns, amazon-route53

We have a hosted zone in Route53 and Alias records to our ELB.  We have failover setup correctly.  But my question is our DNS is hosted elsewhere.  Right now we have a CNAME to our primary ELB target.  In order to get failover to be automatic we would need a CNAME to the actual site name correct?

(These are all examples)

3rd party DNS:
www.testsite.com CNAME Test-872627.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com

Route53:
www.testsite.com -> Primary -> Test-872627.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
www.testsite.com -> Secondary -> Test-822129.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com

So we would basically need something like:
www.testsite2.com CNAME www.testsite.com

Or am I crazy?  From my reading I see that Route53 is automatic but that appears only if the DNS is hosted there.  So if the primary failed and the secondary record kicked in 3rd party DNS is still using a CNAME which points to the primary ELB target.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using CNAME use A record. The type should be A-IPv4 address and in the alias target set your elb_public_dns name. I think this can solve the issue

Comment: But even with an A record and using the ELB DNS name it will still only return that ELB DNS name.  In the event of a failover.  It will not return the secondary ELB DNS name.

Comment: your final domain will be www.testsite2.com right??

Comment: No.  The endpoint is www.testsite.com which points to the ELBs.  This is all in Route53.  This works.  I'm not concerned with the Route53 portion.  Its the 3rd party DNS.  Right now they have a CNAME to our primary ELB.  So lets say the primary record stops responding in Route53 and fails over to the secondary.  The third party CNAME record is still pointing to the primary ELB.